# How to tick check-boxes on page load according to the value of radio button in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<script>
//For the rooms
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tpropval = $('input[name=Typeofproperty]:checked').val()
    if (tpropval != 'Plot' || tpropval != 'Studio Appartment') {
        $('#chkroomdetails').show();         

    }

    else {
        $('#chkroomdetails').hide();

    }
})
```

```
 <div id="chkroomdetails" class="roomdetails">

                    <h5>* Room Details :</h5>


                    <input type="checkbox" class="roomdetails" name="Roomdetails" id="1bed" value="1BHK" />1 BHK



                      <input type="checkbox" class="roomdetails" name="Roomdetails" id="2bed" value="2BHK" />2 BHK



                      <input type="checkbox" class="roomdetails" name="Roomdetails" id="3bed" value="3BHK" />3 BHK



                      <input type="checkbox" class="roomdetails" name="Roomdetails" id="4bed" value="4BHK" />4 BHK


                      <input type="checkbox" class="roomdetails" name="Roomdetails" id="5bed" value="5BHK" />5 BHK

         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Roomdetails)
                </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arr = $("#hiddenroomdetails").val().split(", ");
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), arr) >= 0) {
            $(this).attr("checked", true);
        }
    });
});
```

I have 2 radio buttons of apartment and house. The attribute called "hiddenroomdetails" is the property of the model which carries the details of the rooms in the type of house like 2BHK and 3BHK. In db they are stored with a comma separation(", "). While retrieving the details uising this jquery I'm not getting the check-boxes ticked on the Edit page.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your script. Perhaps check the value of `@Model.Roomdetails` (its case sensitive)

Comment: I checked it by using <input type="text".. instead of hidden. value are appearing properly in the text box.

Comment: Then there is something else interfering with your script. Do you have other code you have not included above?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - check the updated code. It tells that if the radio button condition is matched only then display check-boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `$(this).attr("checked", true);` use `$(this).prop("checked", true);` or use `$(this).attr("checked", "checked");`

After your edit your complete jquery code should be like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var tpropval = $('input[name=Typeofproperty]:checked').val()
  if (tpropval != 'Plot' || tpropval != 'Studio Appartment') {         
    var arr = $("#hiddenroomdetails").val().split(", ");
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
      if ($.inArray($(this).val(), arr) > -1) {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
      }
    });
    $('#chkroomdetails').show();
  }

  else {
    $('#chkroomdetails').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: This way  if the value in hidden field is "2BHK, 3BHK". then only 2BHK is being displayed. For values having single value like "2BHK" there is no ticking.

Comment: No change bro. Its still the same thing.

Comment: just try using $.trim() to remove white space and see updated answer also..it will work..just check carefully there may be problem somewhere else

Comment: No its not. I tried everything. In one more page I implemented same thing there this jquery was working for number of checkboxes. But the difference is that the check-boxes appeared on page load withou any condition but here they are displayed if one of the radio buttons has the value true.

Comment: @Smokingmonkey..so i think this is the problem .. the checkboxes are not there on page load..how you are generating checkboxes then with jquery???

Comment: I mean check-boxes are hidden if the if condition fails otherwise they are shown. If shown then we match the value from the array and tick them.

Comment: @Smokingmonkey...strange ...just use browser console and see there if its coming inside if statement of $.inArray().. there is problem somewhere else..just check cases also because javascript is case sensitive and use $.trim() to remove white spaces..

Comment: I checked the db. There I updated the Roomdetails column with "3BHK" for all the rows and it showed correct result. Then I did the same thing for "3BHK, 2BHK" and again it ticked the corresponding boxes.There was some problem with spaces only I think.

Comment: @Smokingmonkey..then why don't instead of saving "3BHK, 2BHK" just save it like "3BHK,2BHK"..with no space in between

Comment: I am working on an old project . My seniors have written some code for saving the check-box values . I didn't want to do anything with that.

Comment: I have changed their code now by (",") split up. By (", ") it wasn't showing the last value ticked. Now its ok. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$(this).attr("checked", "checked");`